# Pandas - compare two rows using custom function

Tags: python, pandas

Function to compare:

```
def get_td(first_date_str, second_date_str):
    tdelta = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.datetime.strptime(second_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return tdelta.days

diff = filtered
for index, row in diff.iterrows():
    diff['difference_in_days'] = get_td(row.date, row.shift(1).date)
```

Problem is that `row.shift(1).date` always return `nan` and I get a TypeError.

Any ideas?

I have tried pandas.apply function, but It work only with single argument functions not two.

one row from dataframe:

```
2018-07-26,+29,753,suncl,,С 4м/с,w0,+21,753,sunc,,С 4м/с,w0
```

Comment: `Any ideas?` - That might depend on what the DataFrame contains. Would you like to include a minimal example? - Please read [mcve].

Comment: Row should be a Series, that looks like a string or something else. How about a **minimal** example of the DataFrame? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: but row is Series. I think problem that series in iterrows() contains only one row on every iteration.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell but I think you want to pass a DataFrame column as the first argument and that same column shifted as the second argument.  Here is a toy example.

```
>>> df
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0    10    13    17
1    20    23    27
2    15    18    22
3    30    33    37
4    45    48    52

>>> def get_td(first_date_str, second_date_str):
    return first_date_str - second_date_str

>>> get_td(df['Col1'], df['Col1'].shift(1))
0     NaN
1    10.0
2    -5.0
3    15.0
4    15.0
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
>>>
```

---

Another more like your example

```
>>> df
         date
0  2011-01-01
1  2011-01-02
2  2011-01-03
3  2011-01-04
4  2011-01-05
5  2011-01-06

>>> def get_td(first,second):
...     return pd.to_datetime(first) - pd.to_datetime(second)

>>> get_td(df['date'],df['date'].shift(1))
0      NaT
1   1 days
2   1 days
3   1 days
4   1 days
5   1 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
>>>
```