# How do I check if the string in the first row is included into the string in the first row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new here so already thank you for your help.

I have two lists. One which includes Airports like "EWR", "LHR", etc. and one which includes routes like FRAEWR, LHREWR, FRASIN, etc.

The output should be a matrix with 0 and 1. 1 if the airport is included in the route and 0 if it is not.

I'm trying to avoid for loops for performance reasons. Is there a way to do this? I'm working with pandas dataframes.
thank you!!

BR

Comment: Hey, you should take a look at this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127806/pandas-compare-two-rows-using-custom-function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where dataframes come in, since you say you have two lists, so let's just work with lists for now.

Since you need to iterate on your data, a loop of some sorts will always be there, be it explicit or hidden "under the hood" of some functions you'll be calling; what we can try to do is limiting the number of iterations. A possible solution is to populate a matrix (i.e. a list of lists) with all zeros, then for each route set the relevant cells to one; this should prove faster than iterating on airports and check in which route each airport is included. So the code could be something like

```
airports=['FRA','EWR','LHR','SIN']
routes=['FRAEWR','LHREWR','FRASIN']
matrix=[[0]*len(routes) for x in range(len(airports))]
for i,r in enumerate(routes):
    matrix[airports.index(r[:3])][i] = 1
    matrix[airports.index(r[3:])][i] = 1
```